# How can I navigate through my component with an URL like 'edition?section=1#s1'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this dataset

```
data() : {

    navigation : {
        section : {
            story : {}
        }
    },
}
```

The navigation display works like this

```
<div v-for="section in navigation.section" :key="section.id"> 
    <section-component :currentSection="section"></section-component>
</div>
```

And I have a simple menu on the left-side that shown with a list how is the structure of my section and stories

```
 - CarsSection
    - StoryMyDreamcar
    - StoryCarGoFast
 - AnimalSection
    -WildLifeStory
```

What I'm trying to do is, when I press to "StoryMyDreamcar" my url changes to something like this `edition?section=1#s1` and display the content of the section's story.

I tried to use Window.location and put the index of each section inside, but it's not working.

```
window.location.search({ section: index })
```

Any idea ? I can use Vue router if it's easier for this kind of things

Comment: You could use Vue router

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: `window.location.search = new URLSearchParams({ section: index })` ?

Comment: I use it inside a 'navigation.section' watcher and I have an infinite loop

Comment: *I can use Vue router if it's easier for this kind of things* - it certainly is, because you're currently reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What I tried to say is : I tried to find some way to do it with Vue Router, but I didn't find any. I find a way this `window.location` but I'm open if my problem can be solved by Vue.router

Comment: @JohnW2Smith The question doesn't contain enough information to suggest anything specific. It's unknown what Vue version you use. it's unknown why urls need to look like that. It's common to use either path or hash to specify a route, not query params. As for query, something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529194/vuejs-render-dynamic-component-with-route-query